# OneToMany on existing object Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm experimenting to get a better idea of how Django works. Take the below test function that creates a **Category, Tag, and Item** representing **Macbook Pros** then adds a **Macbook Pro** to that Category, Tag, and Item (product).

**Relevant Models:** (Note I am in the middle of troubleshooting, models may not exactly represent what they were at the time of the question)

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    introduction = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    quanity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    is_retired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add(self):
        pass

    def remove(self):
        pass

    def retire(self): # Rex came up with this, roll credits.
        pass 

    def count(self):
        pass

class OnHand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial
```

**Test Cases:**

```
def make_macbook():
    """ Create a Manufacturer for Apple """
    apple = Manufacturer(name='Apple', rep_name='Jason Wilburn', support_number='1-800-Apple')
    apple.save()
    print('Manufacturer name: {}'.format(apple))

    """ Create a Category for Laptops """
    laptop = Category(name='Laptops')
    laptop.save()
    print('Category name: {}'.format(laptop))

    """ Create a Tag for Mac """
    mac = Tag(title='mac')
    mac.save()
    print('Tag name: {}'.format(mac))

    """ Create a MacBook Item """
    macbook = Item(name='Macbook Pro', description='15.5" Macbook Pro, 2018 Model', manufacturer=apple)
    macbook.save()
    print('Item name: {}'.format(macbook))

    """ Create a MacBook OnHand item """
    newMac = OnHand(name='MacBook Pro 15.5"', serial='SC02XP0NRJGH5', asset='DEPSC02XP0NRJGH5', product=macbook)
    newMac.save()


    return newMac.product
```

What I'm testing now is adding new **OnHand** objects to the **Category, Tag, and Item**.

Here is what I have:

```
def add_macbook():
    """ Find MacBook Item """
    macbook = Item.objects.filter(name='Macbook Pro')

    """ Create a MacBook OnHand item """
    newMac = OnHand(name='MacBook Pro 15.5"', serial='000000000000000', asset='DEP0000000000000', product=macbook)
    newMac.save()
```

I'm confronted with 2 problems:

1. Class 'Item' has no 'objects' member
2. ValueError: Cannot assign "]>": "OnHand.product" must be a "Item" instance.

How would I get an existing **Item** instance to associate?

I have also tried:

```
def add_macbook():
    """ Find MacBook Item """
    macbook = Item.objects.get(name='Macbook Pro')

    """ Create a MacBook OnHand item """
    newMac = OnHand(name='MacBook Pro 15.5"', serial='000000000000000', asset='DEP0000000000000')
    newMac.save()
    macbook.product.add(newMac)
```

Which presents me with the obvious *'Item' has no attribute 'product'* because it obviously doesn't. I tried this because of how my `Tag` model works.

Comment: If you're going to down vote please let me know why you're down voting so it can be resolved. :)

Comment: Can you share your `models.py` file?

Comment: Added to edit. Let me know if you need to see any others. I just included the most relevant.

Comment: Should I maybe be getting the ID of `macbook` under `add_macbook()` and just "insert" that into the `product` attribute on the `newMac` `OnHand()` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` function returns a queryset rather than a single model instance and you can't assign an entire queryset as a foreign key. On the other hand `.get()` will return a single model instance. You almost had the right combination. Try this:

```
def add_macbook():
    """ Find MacBook Item """
    macbook = Item.objects.get(name='Macbook Pro')


    """ Create a MacBook OnHand item """
    newMac = OnHand(
        name='MacBook Pro 15.5"',
        serial='000000000000000',
        asset='DEP0000000000000',
        product=macbook
    )
    newMac.save()
```

That `Class 'Item' has no 'objects' member` error doesn't make sense to me. Is it maybe just an IDE warning?

Here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#filter) for the filter function.

Comment: Yeah the error appears to just be the IDE because there's no environment variables set so its correct, until opening the django shell, there is no objects member.

Comment: This does work! So I wasn't far off in my own troubleshooting here, but thought myself into a logic loop again haha. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Sure, glad it helped.